# How can I override this Ruby variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The original code looks like this:

```
module Acme
  class Address
    STREET_NAME = "123 acme inc drive".freeze

    ..
    ..
  end
end
```

This is a 3rd party gem, I was hoping I could modify the `STREET_NAME` variable in a initializer somehow, without having to edit the source code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just reassign it:

```
Acme::Address::STREET_NAME = "1 Infinite Loop"
```

Freezing an object freezes just that: *the object*, not the variable (reference) itself. Reassigning a constant will give you a warning though:

> warning: already initialized constant `STREET_NAME`

since it's generally not a good idea to reassign a constant—but this is Ruby, and since everything is dynamic, constants aren't really constant. Doing this in an initializer should work just fine.

Comment: Just to add: if you want to avoid the warning, you can do `Acme::Address.send :remove_const, :STREET_NAME` before reassigning.